# Jquery on click event is not working on dynamically added Custom tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-trigger

Jquery on click event is not working on dynamically added Custom tags

My code is

```
  $("[addtoShip='yes']").on('click', function() {
         alert('Ship added')
  });
```

Href for `<a href="#" addtoShip='yes' myVal="10235">`add more to Ship`</a>`

I am trying using `.on`  But still it's not working

Comment: may be `$(document).on('click', "[addtoShip='yes']", function() {`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt, I have tested that also but no luck

Comment: Ask a new question and paste some more code into that .. try to be specific.. add your html and script code where you are adding the dynamic element. @MangeshSatheIND

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document/CommonParentSelector).on('click', "[addtoShip='yes']", function () {
    alert('Ship added')
});
```

Comment: It Worked   $(document).on('click', "[densitybtn='yes']", function() {}) But i did'nt get CommonParentSelector